# How to use __iter__ and __next__ for iteration in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, iterator, iteration

I am trying to learn how iterators, generators and decorators works in python based on the tutorials in [this](http://pymbook.readthedocs.org/en/latest/igd.html) website.

In the first example, he/she demonstrate a simple example as below:

```
class Count:
    def __init__(self, low, high):
        self.low = low
        self.high = high

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.current > self.high:
            raise StopIteration
        else:
            self.current +=1
            return self.current -1
```

The problem is, I can't iterate over objects of this class:

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
>>> c = Count(1, 10)
>>> for i in c:
    print i



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    for i in c:
TypeError: instance has no next() method
>>>
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That tutorial appears to be for Python *3*.

In Python 2 iterators must have the [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#iterator.next) method ([PEP 3114](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3114) - *Renaming iterator.next() to iterator.__next__()*):

```
class Count:
    def __init__(self, low, high):
        self.current = low
        self.high = high

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        if self.current > self.high:
            raise StopIteration
        else:
            self.current +=1
            return self.current -1
```

Comment: Thank you. Anyway, why I don't receive _Undefined Variable_ error for `self.current`? what is its value when the line `self.current +=1` run for first time?

Comment: @Abraham I think it should be `self.current = low`

Comment: @Abraham: You will indeed get an error.  You should initialize `self.current` in `__init__`.

Comment: @Abraham - what do you get if you print ```self.current``` as the first statement of ```next()```?

Comment: @wwii You are right. I got an error. I defined it in `__init__` now.

Comment: An alternative solution to renaming `__next__` to `next` in your function would be to switch Python interpreters so that you're using Python 3 like your tutorial expects. Many aspects of Python 3 are better than Python 2, most notably its handling of Unicode text. There are some modules that are only available for Python 2, but that number is diminishing steadily, so unless you're sure you need one of them already, I'd suggest learning Python 3 first, rather than learning Python 2 and then learning how to port your code to Python 3 later on.